# Adding values from outside scope in two different sql tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In procedure below,I'm updating and inserting into docmeta and documenthistory table respectively.
I've calculated the value of 'paymentterm' in docmeta update with code as shown below. Now i want to insert the same paymentterm vale in documenthistory table as well(highlighted in bold and italics below).But since paymenterm in docmeta has limited scope i'm not able to use this value in documenthistory table even if i write the complete paymentterm select statement i.e. SELECT paymentterm
        FROM temp_pay_term
        WHERE pid   = d.xProject_id
        AND rownum <= 1

How can i make the code below workable
...................................................................

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PAYTERMUPDATE
IS
  RecordCount INT;
  varDID      NUMBER(38);
BEGIN
  RecordCount :=0;
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO RecordCount
  FROM temp_pay_term;
  IF RecordCount > 0 THEN
    FOR X       IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT r.ddocName
    FROM temp_Pay_Term ptq,
      docMeta d,
      revisions r
    WHERE TO_CHAR(ptq.pid) = d.xproject_id
    AND r.did              = d.did
    )
    LOOP
      SELECT MAX(did)
      INTO varDid
      FROM revisions r
      WHERE r.ddocname = X.ddocName
      GROUP BY r.ddocname;
      UPDATE docmeta d
      SET paymentterm =
        (SELECT paymentterm
        FROM temp_pay_term
        WHERE pid   = d.xProject_id
        AND rownum <= 1
        )
      WHERE d.did = vardid;
      INSERT
      INTO DOCUMENTHISTORY
        (
          dactionmillis,
          dactiondate,
          did,
          drevclassid,
          duser,
          ddocname,
          daction,
          dsecuritygroup,
          ***paymentterm***
        )
      SELECT to_number(TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'FF')) AS dactionmillis,
        TRUNC(systimestamp,'dd')                   AS dactiondate,
        did,
        drevclassid,
        'sysadmin' AS duser,
        ddocname,
        'Update' AS daction,
        dsecuritygroup,
        ***PAYMENTTERM***
      FROM revisions
      WHERE did = vardid;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END PAYTERMUPDATE; -- PL SQL code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you can return *paymentterm* using `returning into`

```
  declare
    ...
    varpayment number;
  begin
    ...

    update docmeta d
    set paymentterm =
        (select paymentterm
         from temp_pay_term
         where pid = d.xproject_id
           and rownum <= 1)
    where d.did = vardid
    returning paymentterm into varpayment;

    /* and then use varpayment */
    ... 
  end;
```

See [returning into documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) for more details

Comment: Thanks Simon. It compiled successfully but is the procedure correct? I'm still not getting values  in my tables. OR am I still missing something?

Comment: if you do not get both values on your tables, could this mean your subquery `select paymentterm from temp_pay_term where pid = d.xproject_id and rownum <= 1` returns no rows or null?

Comment: Right. rownum <= 1 is creating the issue

Comment: I'm getting below error while executing this procedure.Am i getting  multiple values in this select and returning is not accepting it is the issue? Does returning takes multiple values. 'If Not', how can we allow multiple rows here.ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "ITAPP_STELLENT_DELFIN16.PAYTERMUPDATE", line 31
ORA-06512: at line 1